# How to change publisher name in package.appxmanifest file for UWP app?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-iot-core-10

How to change publisher name in package.appxmanifest file for UWP app?

Its not possible to change publisher name in package.appxmanifest file. I tried to edit package.appxmanifest file for a while its reflecting but while creating App package again its taking default value.

But its possible to edit Package Name and package family name.

Comment: Are you creating a App package for Microsoft Store? In that case the values are overridden by the Microsoft Store account values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to create a package for Windows Store submission, you could associate your project with Store and all the identity info in Package manifest will match the value in Dev Center (including `publisher name` and `package identity name`). And you will get a StoreKey.pfx certificate which has the same publisher info as your manifest and will be used for code signing when you create package.

If you want to create a package without publishing to Store, you need to create a new certificate for your app when you change the publisher name in package manifest. Because if you just change the value in manifest, it will still use the default publisher name value from the TemporaryKey.pfx when you package the app.

For more details, you could refer to [**Create a self-signed certificate**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing#create-a-self-signed-certificate).